# Filter a list property of a list of objects in scala

Tags: java, list, scala, filter, seq

I am trying trying to filter a list property of a list of objects in scala. For example:

Class defined in java

```
public class Result{
    private Collection<Person> persons= new ArrayList();
    public Collection<Person> getPersons() {return this.persons;}
}

public class Person{
    public String name
}
```

My filter function is returning a list of String instead of a list of Result

```
val listOfResutlts = Seq.empty[Result]  // imagine this was filled with a bunch of Result objects

listOfResutlts.map(
    result => result.getPersons.filter(person => person.name=="xx")
)
```

**UPDATE**
I want to get back all the results in the listOfResults with the names properpty of each Result being filtered.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a List[String]? For what I read, you should be getting a List[Collection[Person]].

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are mapping each result to a filtered collection of persons. if you want to wrap those collections back on to results (probably filtering empty results??), you would need something like this:

```
listOfResutlts.flatMap(res => {
   val filtered = res.getPersons.filter(_.name=="xx")
   if(filtered.isEmpty) None else Some(new Result(filtered))
}
```

Do note that you need to be able to construct a new Result from a new set of Person.